# Why is a float required, and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, floating-point

I have this Decision Tree algorithm:

```
import sys
from class_vis import prettyPicture
from prep_terrain_data import makeTerrainData

import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test = makeTerrainData()

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
prediction = clf.predict(features_test, labels_test)
acc = accuracy_score(labels_test, prediction)

def submitAccuracies():
  return {"acc":round(acc,3)}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_yafetikvhw/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import studentMain
  File "/tmp/vmuser_yafetikvhw/studentMain.py", line 10, in <module>
    student_output = student_code.submitAccuracies()
  File "/tmp/vmuser_yafetikvhw/decisionTreeAccuracyQuiz.py", line 34, in submitAccuracies
    return float({"acc":round(acc,3)})
TypeError: a float is required
```

I'm stuck here. I've tried turning my input into a float but still get same error. For example: acc = acc/1.0 or acc = float(acc)

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the `{"acc": …}` bit from? Is `submitAccuracies` supposed to return a dict, or a float?

Comment: That was already there. I am filling in a partially coded quiz. But yes, I think I'm returning a dict. For example: acc: .908

Comment: Does your file actually say `return {"acc":round(acc,3)}`, or does it say `return float({"acc":round(acc,3)})`? The stack trace suggests the latter. Make sure you’re saving changes to the right file.

Comment: It actually says  return {"acc":round(acc,3)}

Comment: So `/tmp/vmuser_yafetikvhw/decisionTreeAccuracyQuiz.py` does not have the word “float” on line 34? Or are you editing some other file and submitting it to something that rewrites your code? =/

Comment: Correct. Float was never a part of original code. I am not submitting it to anything that rewrites the code. It's an online compiler too, not that it might help.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to know why, however, I was getting that message.

Answer (score 0):

score

> returns the number of correctly classified samples (int).

From here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Try this one:

```
return {"acc":round(float(acc), 3)}
```